# Need help in using decode or case function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need a column where, when enddate is null or greater then sysdate then display status value as "active" or else "inactive".

Can I use decode or case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
   Select CASE WHEN (t.c1 is null or t.c1 >Sysdate) THEN 'ACTIVE' ELSE 'INACTIVE' end 
   from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to have a case statement like this since there is no much difference in performance and `CASE` is more clear.

```
SELECT
      CASE
          WHEN ( ENDDATE IS NULL
               OR ENDDATE > SYSDATE )
          THEN
              'ACTIVE'
          ELSE
              'INACTIVE'
      END
          AS CHECK_ACTIVE_STATUD
FROM
      YOUR_TABLE;
```